# Elegant way to add a pair of back ticks to the resulting string from javascript string interpolation?

Tags: javascript, string-interpolation

I'm using string interpolation to create a string that I am sending to another service. This other service allows for back ticks to format text when it is displayed. I would like to include back ticks in this string so that it is more readable to the end user.

I found *a* way, but it seems sloppy. It takes me 6 characters to add 1 character to my output, and sends my pinkies all over the keyboard, making it difficult to type:

```
const myString = `There will be one here -> ${'`'} and one here -> ${'`'}.`;
// There will be one here -> ` and one here -> `.
```

Is there a better way I could do this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Funny enough, I actually stumbled across that same link myself looking up how to do something different seconds before thinking to come back here and check if I had any responses... both you and the user who posted an answer sent the same link. I think the universe is telling me to read something...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use backslashes to escape them:

> To escape a back-tick in a template literal, put a backslash \ before the back-tick. - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
const myString = `There will be one here -> ${'`'} and one here -> ${'`'}.`;
const myString2 = `There will be one here -> \` and one here -> \`.`;

console.log(myString === myString2);
```

Comment: I have no clue what I did wrong when I tried this earlier, but it didn't work so i passed it off and came up with my roundabout solution. Thanks!